# Makefile cppUtest output reformat

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, make

I need to reformat the output of a program created with cppUtest during my build from inside a makefile.

I have this target in my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: runalltests
runalltests: ##@tests Run all tests.
    $(ECHO)
    @./runAlltests
```

That executes the *'runalltests'* program which outputs this text into terminal. (The dots are important)

```
......
OK (6 tests, 6 ran, 7 checks, 0 ignored, 0 filtered out, 0 ms)
```

I know from other answers in the stack overflow site that I need **awk**, **sed** or **grep** (or something I do not know of). But I can not figure it out for a long time now on how to do it so I gave up trying and ask here.

**I want to reformat the output into adding 4 spaces before each line.**

For example this:

```
 (Four spaces here)......
 (Four spaces here)OK (6 tests, 6 ran, 7 checks, 0 ignored, 0 filtered out, 0 ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with **`sed`**:

```
<runalltests_output> | sed 's/^/    /'
```